# How can I use put function of REST as an alternative to post function to save multiple data?

Tags: python-3.x, firebase, rest, firebase-realtime-database

I've been trying to save custom keys on firebase realtime database and I don't want to use post method since it generates unique keys.
I tried using put but that just functions like set method and adds single data whereas I want to add multiple data.

```
   from firebase import firebase 
   firebase=firebase.FirebaseApplication('link',None)
   for i in range(len(essential)):
      firebase.put('/extempore','essential',{i: essential[i]})
```

Comment: Send there json.. Than u can send multiple data

Comment: {i: essential[i]} is a json itself. Can you please elaborate what you trying to say?

Comment: create some object and deserialize json to it in put method.. so you can have more data there